NodeJs and Postgres-Connection terminated unexpectedly
I'm trying to connect my Node project to Postgres.
My server is running in the project.
In Postgres, when I execute a data retrieval command, it also return me the correct data.
But when he wants to retrieve data in the get method in the reposutory file in the project.
He doesn't succeed and i have this erorr:Connection terminated unexpectedly
when i run the project i have in my console these messeges:

Database user: postgres
Database host: xxx
Database name: Dependencies_Planner
Database password: xxx
Database port: 5432
Server is running on port 3000

but ehwn i put this url in postman:http://localhost:3000/api/requestor-names
i got this erorr in postman:Internal Server Error and status :500.
and these erorrs in the console:

controller
Entering getAllProductManagerNames method
Error executing query in getAllProductManagerNames: Error: Connection terminated unexpectedly
at C:\Users\USER\Desktop\DP\Dependencies-Planner-PRD\node_modules\pg-pool\index.js:45:11
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
Error fetching requestor names: Error: Connection terminated unexpectedly
at C:\Users\USER\Desktop\DP\Dependencies-Planner-PRD\node_modules\pg-pool\index.js:45:11
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)

I put here all the files in my project that are related to the method.
this is my .env file:
PGUSER="postgres"
PGHOST="xxx"
PGDATABASE="Dependencies_Planner"
PGPASSWORD="xxx"
PGPORT=5432
EXPRESS_PORT=3000
PGPASSWORD="***" # credentials removed

this is my db file:
import { Pool } from 'pg';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';

dotenv.config();
console.log('Database user:', process.env.PGUSER);
console.log('Database host:', process.env.PGHOST);
console.log('Database name:', process.env.PGDATABASE);
console.log('Database password:', process.env.PGPASSWORD); 
console.log('Database port:', process.env.PGPORT);



const pool = new Pool({
  user: process.env.PGUSER,
  host: process.env.PGHOST,
  database: process.env.PGDATABASE,
 password: process.env.PGPASSWORD, 
  port: Number(process.env.PGPORT),
  
});

export default pool;


this is my repository file:
import pool from '../config/db';

export default class ProductManagerRepo {
    static async getAllProductManagerNames(): Promise<{ name: string }[]> {
        try {
            console.log('Entering getAllProductManagerNames method');
            const result = await pool.query('SELECT name FROM productmanager');
            console.log('Query executed successfully, result:', result.rows);
            return result.rows;
        } catch (err) {
            console.error('Error executing query in getAllProductManagerNames:', err);
            throw err;
        }
    }
}


this is my controller file:
import { Request, Response } from 'express';
import ProductManagerRepo from '../repositories/productManagerRepo';



export const getRequestorNames = async (req: Request, res: Response): Promise<void> => {
    console.log('controller')
    try {
      const productManagerNames = await ProductManagerRepo.getAllProductManagerNames();
      res.json(productManagerNames);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error fetching requestor names:', error);
      res.status(500).send('Internal Server Error');
    }
  };


this is my model file :
export interface ProductManager{
    email:string,
    name:string,
    groupId:number
    };

this is my app file:
import express from 'express';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import ProductmanagerRoutes from './src/routes/productManagerRoutes'

dotenv.config();

const app = express();
const port = process.env.EXPRESS_PORT || 3000;

app.use(express.json());


app.use('/api', ProductmanagerRoutes);

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
});


First of all: Do not EVER share credentials online. Not even for toy systems ... (edited your code snippet accordingly). Wrt you issue: I am not thouroughly familiar with your setup but I think you are missing to build a DB connection to your DB pool, along the lines of const dbc = await pool.connect(); const result = await dbc.query('SELECT name FROM productmanager');. The connection pool just manages (efficiently) the connections to the DB which are the actual handles to use for querying.

"when i run the project i have in my console these messeges:" - so what? None of these say that an actual connection to the database was successful

@collapsar In node-postgres, the pool itself also has a .query() method for one-off queries that just acquires and releases a client (a connection) under the hood

In the end I found the answer myself
My database was in the AWS cloud so I had to add in the constructor that it connects to postgreSQL:
ssl:{
rejectUnauthorized: false

}
to this constructor:
const pool = new Pool({
user: process.env.PGUSER,
host: process.env.PGHOST,
database: process.env.PGDATABASE,
password: process.env.PGPASSWORD, 
port: Number(process.env.PGPORT),

});

